# PHP Sum array - only getting 1st result from DB

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fetching an array from my DB and I want to sum all the results, but I only seem to be getting the first result from the DB instead of all the results.

**PHP CODE:**

```
$jobID = $_GET['jobID'];

$sql_delivqty = "SELECT delQTY
                 FROM deliveries
                 WHERE jobID = '$jobID'
                 ";

$query_delivqty = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_delivqty) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$row_delivqty = mysqli_fetch_array($query_delivqty);

if ($row_delivqty <= 0) {
    $delivqty = 0;
} else {
    $delivqty = array_sum($row_delivqty);
}
```

**VAR_DUMP:**

```
var_dump($row_delivqty);

array (size=2)
0 => string '560' (length=3)
'delQTY' => string '560' (length=3)
```

**Expected Result:**

> 560 + 85 + 25 = 670

This is not an exact duplicate of another question. The question suggested is trying to sum a column in a DB. I'm trying to sum specific rows in a DB.

Comment: `SELECT SUM(delQTY) ...`. And use a prepared statement.

Comment: from php.net `mysqli_fetch_array() is an extended version of the mysqli_fetch_row() function.`

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of `mysqli_fetch_array`. "It returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row. NULL if there are no more rows in result-set." You are only using the first row in your query result, not all 3 of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do [SUM](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_sum.asp) in the query itself:-

```
$sql_delivqty = "SELECT SUM(delQTY) AS total
                 FROM deliveries
                 WHERE jobID = '$jobID'";

$query_delivqty = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_delivqty) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$row_delivqty = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_delivqty);

echo $row_delivqty['total'];
```

***Note:-*** This Query is vulnerable to ***`SQL Injection`***. So use ***`prepared statements`*** of `mysqli_*` to prevent from it.

Reference:- [mysqli::prepare Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

***For your help do like below (`prepared statement way`):-***

```
$jobID = $_GET['jobID'];
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT SUM(delQTY) AS total FROM deliveries WHERE jobID = ?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $jobID);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row_delivqty);

    /* fetch value */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    echo $row_delivqty['total'];

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Comment: Doing the SUM in the query worked perfectly - thanks Alive to Die

Comment: @jeroen  i hope  my answer is perfect now.